# clamav shows twice in htop, takes a lot of memory and service has error but is running

Tags: memory-usage, vps, clamav

When showing the status of clamav, I see the following

```
clamav-daemon.service - Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d
           └─extend.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-02-07 12:03:15 UTC; 1s ago
     Docs: man:clamd(8)
           man:clamd.conf(5)
           https://www.clamav.net/documents/
  Process: 3483 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown clamav /run/clamav (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3482 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir /run/clamav (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3484 (clamd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 614)
   CGroup: /system.slice/clamav-daemon.service
           └─3484 /usr/sbin/clamd --foreground=true

Feb 07 12:03:15 vps48064754.local systemd[1]: Starting Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon...
Feb 07 12:03:15 vps48064754.local systemd[1]: Started Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon.
```

How can I check the reason for this error: `process 3482 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir /run/clamav (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`? As you can see, it's still running so I'm not sure what's going on.

Also, when running htop, I see clamav twice and it takes 800+ memory:

```
3532 clamav     20   0 1113M  866M 16960 S  0.0 42.3  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/clamd --foreground=true 

3484 clamav     20   0 1113M  866M 16960 S  0.0 42.3  0:15.20 /usr/sbin/clamd --foreground=true
```

The time of 3484 is 0:15 while 3532 is 0:00. I read that this is how clamav works but what about some kind of a job that wakes up every hour, do the magic and goes to sleep instead?

Thanks

Comment: The most likely reason for the failure is that the file already exists (and perhaps has existed for a very long time). In other words, the failure is NOT an error, but is expected behavior. Your second question is a "what if?" question for developers, and is unlikely to be answered here.

Comment: You mean it tries to create a folder that is already there, why trying to do that each time and showing a failure?

Comment: Because the directory NOT existing would indeed be a process-stopping Error.

Comment: Ofcourse, I meant a simple if statement to check instead of throwing it as an error :) Now I'm left with the memory hog, the fact it appears twice and how to (maybe) setup to wakeup every X hours instead of hogging the memory 24/7

Comment: I'm sure the developers would welcome your patch to the systemd job, which is likely unrelated to memory usage. Your question about memory usage is unclear: Are you asking how to diagnose a memory leal? Are you asking how much memory clam should be using? Are you asking something else?

Comment: I'm asking 1. Is 800mb makes sense. 2. Showing 2 pids with 40+% each makes sense and 3. Can I set clamav to wake up every hour do its thing and go to sleep instead of how it is now. Thanks